# How to store a value from a MySQL database in a C variable

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I'm starting with C and MySQL, I have created a database with some columns and I want to store two of them and use it in other parts of the code. In the example that I give i'm trying to store one value of "latitud" from de database in variable float lat, but it give me an error in the core. Do you know how can I solve this? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>


#define HOST "localhost"
#define USER "victor"
#define PASS "tfg"
#define DATABASE "barcos"
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    MYSQL *con;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    
    con = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!mysql_real_connect(con, HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE, 0, NULL, 0)){ // CONEXIÓN A LA BASE DE DATOS
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    return 1;
    }
    mysql_query(con, "SELECT latitud FROM BARCOS ");
    res = mysql_store_result(con);
    printf("latitud:\n");
    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=0)
    printf("%s\n", row[0]);
    float lat = row[0] ? atof(row[0]) : 0.0;
    printf("%f", lat);
    
    
    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(con);
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but it give me an error in the core.`? What's the error message? Did you try to step through your code using a debugger? How far do you get?

Answer (score 0):

What is `res` after

```
res = mysql_store_result(con); // res could be NULL, you do not check the result
```

Then you fetch all rows and print them

```
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=0) // no braces, that means, ...
    printf("%s\n", row[0]);             // print only the first element from each row
```

but afterwards you call

```
//row is NULL here, because you exhausted the set in the loop before
float lat = row[0] ? atof(row[0]) : 0.0;
```

and you cannot dereference a NULL pointer.

From [mysql_store_result](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-store-result.html):

> **Return Values**
> A pointer to a MYSQL_RES result structure with the results. NULL if the statement did not return a result set or an error occurred.

From [mysql_fetch_row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-fetch-row.html):

> **Return Values**
> A MYSQL_ROW structure for the next row, or NULL (either if there are no more rows or when an error occurred).

Comment: What do you men with "check res here for NULL"  and with '''row == NULL (!)'''

Comment: I' ve added some more info to the anwer, hope it's much clearer now.

Comment: Ok I think I can see where the problem is, I have to improve my use of MySQL language, thank you!!